# PropertyGrid alike with dgrid

Tags: dgrid

I'd like to create a PropertyGrid alike using dgrid (and dojo). As far as I can see, a single column may only contain a single editor type. Is there any workaround to have different editor controls for different cells in the same row?

The Editor mixin seems to create a single cached editor control per row, but maybe there is something I have missed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no mixin available to achieve the functionality that you have described. But, you could do one of the two things.

1) Instead of using editor, you could use the renderCell function in the columns to return different inputs/widgets depending on the column value/row data. In this case you would need handle the events and update the store.

2) If you still want to use editor, there is a workaround. by using dojo/aspect. You would need to listen to the insertRow method of the grid. And update the cell with appropriate widgets for the cell element. Below is the snippet for the same.

```
aspect.after(grid, "insertRow", lang.hitch(this, 'updateRowWidgets'));

function updateRowWidgets(rowElement){
    var cell = grid.cell(rowElement, <columnid>);
    var rowdata = cell.row.data;

    var rowWidget = .... //Create your widget according to row data.
    cell.element.widget = rowWidget;

    return rowElement; // remember to return this.
}
```

Hope this was helpful.

UPDATE: The second option would work only with editOn, as the widget will be shown/added to grid after the editOn event, and you would be able to switch the widget before that happens. Otherwise the widgets would be added to the grid before insertRow is completed.

Comment: Thanks, the first option seemed to be most promising, but as I've been stuck I tried the second one. In updateRowWidgets, cell.element is undefined. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: The cell.element cannot be undefined as it is the node of the cell. There can be 2 possiblity where it can be undefined. 1) the cell has not been generated. 2) the columnid passed as argument is wrong.